# Javascript (jQuery) loading modal until database queries end on php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I have many mysql queries on the page. Until they are done, i'd like to show() a modal on my page. Modal is ready.

My Algorithm :

```
page.onload -> show loading modal
/*wait until all the queries end*/
hide loading modal.
```

how can i handle wait until all the queries end part ?

Thanks in advance.

---Edit---

I am using laravel debugbar. Debugbar shows me as following :
[image]

---Update--

Javascript file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTab a').on('load', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    },onLoadMyTab());
}

function onLoadMyTab(){
   //postRoute is on my routes.php and data is including the values
   $.post("postRoute", function(data)){
      //some javascript code, just for UI
   }
}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::post('postRoute', array(
   'uses' => 'myController@myPostFunction'
   'as' => 'postRoute'
));
```

myController.php

```
public function myPostFunction(){
   //some database queries here, returning JSON to my onLoadMyTab js function
   //which returns as data to onLoadMyTab js function.
}
```

Hope i could make sense.

Comment: are the queries in some sort of Ajax request?

Comment: @BillPull both ajax and direct mysql requests through php, including both post and get methods.

Comment: can you post how you are calling the AJAX queries like how your scripts are being loaded and when they are called?

Comment: why wouldn't be better way to handle through page loader like pacejs?

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues here:

1. You have an error in your DOM ready handler. Within `$(...).on()` the third argument is the callback called whenever the event is emitted. http://api.jquery.com/on/

You are actually passing in `undefined` into the callback because you called `onLoadMyTab` which returns undefined implicitly.

You probably want to just call the your `onLoadMyTab` immediately when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(onLoadMyTab);
```

2. $.post will make an ajax request and call the second param when the request completes.

   ```
   function onLoadMyTab() {
       $.post("postRoute", function(data)){
           // show modal with data here
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I'll feedback when i am able to test.